# Шорткод формы Contact Form 7 средствами Ajax не работает

Tags: jquery, php, wordpress, javascript

Доброго времени суток, Всем Всем Всем!
Была создана форма средствами плагина `Contact Form 7, шорткод [contact-form-7 id="247" title="CallMe Header Modal"]`. Средствами `jQuery` навешиваю на событие клика следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function get_callme_modal_header() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=add_callme_modal_header_ajax",
            success: function(response){
                $('#callme_header_link').after(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#callme_header_link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        get_callme_modal_header();

    });

});
```

Все бы ничего, но выдергивается исключительно сам код шорткода.
Пхп:

```
function modal_callme_header_handler( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 'call_me',
        'shortcode' => '[contact-form-7 id="247" title="CallMe Header Modal"]',
    ), $atts ) );

    $modal_content = <<<EOT
<div class="modal fade" id="$id" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
EOT;

    $modal_content .= "\r\n".do_shortcode("$shortcode")."\r\n";

    $modal_content .= <<<EOT
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
EOT;

    return $modal_content;
}

add_shortcode('modal_callme_header', 'modal_callme_header_handler');

function add_callme_modal_header_ajax() {
    echo do_shortcode('[modal_callme_header]');
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_add_callme_modal_header_ajax', 'add_callme_modal_header_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_callme_modal_header_ajax', 'add_callme_modal_header_ajax');
```

Задача такова, необходимо чтобы при клике по ссылке появлялось модальное окно-заявка на звонок, реализовать это необходимо средствами аякс. Пожалуйста помогите решить данный трабл, не пойму в чем дело!
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @scorp24, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Iranda, не совсем понял причем здесь это. Все отформатировано вроде...